# Inflate only the circle in the binary occupancy grid map Matlab

Tags: matlab, occupancy-map

I want to create filled circle for the binaryoccupancy grid map in Matlab. I wrote the code as follows,

```
% Create a binary occupancy grid map
map = binaryOccupancyMap(10, 10, 10);

theta = linspace(0,2*pi);
x5 = 6.0+cos(theta); % x circle coordinates
y5 = 6.0+sin(theta); % y circle coordinates
setOccupancy(map, [x5; y5]', 1);

figure
show(map)
```

The output of the above code block is the above picture [image]

However, I want a circle that is filled by the inside. Something like [that](https://www.mathworks.com/help/robotics/ug/occupancy-grids.html). But I can not use the inflate function since I have other objects in the map. I only want to inflate the circle.

What should be the way to that?

Comment: specific to a circle: would something like this be helpful: `x = 1:100; y = (1:100).'; m = (x-60).^2 + (y-60).^2 < 100; figure; imagesc(m); colormap gray;`